# Do que os europeus chamam os "marimbondos"?

Tags: português-brasileiro, português-europeu, palavra-para-ideia

Estava fazendo uma pesquisa e deparei-me com o seguinte texto:

> As vespas são insetos pertencentes à ordem dos himenópteros responsáveis pela polinização de diversas espécies de plantas. Dividem-se nas subordens *Apocrita* e *Symphyta*. As larvas da subordem *Apocrita* são usualmente carnívoras ou parasitoides, enquanto que as da *Symphyta* são herbívoras. **No Brasil e em Angola são chamadas de marimbondos, as vespas da família *Vespidae*, *Pompilidae* ou *Sphecidae***. [(Wikipédia.)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vespa)

Estes termos taxonômicos em latim podem ser resumidos por "vespas que ferroam seres humanos", um subconjunto bem reduzido de insetos. A maioria das espécies de vespas não possui ferrão, e a maioria das restantes evita todo o contato possível com seres humanos.  Das 80 mil espécies catalogadas de vespas, estima-se que somente 5 mil sejam "marimbondos".

A origem etimológica do nome vem do quimbundo, dialeto falado pelos escravos angolanos trazidos ao Brasil, o que explica a inexistência da palavra em terras lusitanas. Mas a pergunta que fica é: do que os portugueses chamam os marimbondos? Ou melhor, como vocês diferenciam marimbondos de vespas inofensivas?

Foto deste inseto asqueroso:

[image]

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/amp/pt.m.wikihow.com/Identificar-Vespas%3Famp%3D1?client=safari

Comment: Ramon, Imagino que aquilo de se ter que passar com o rato sobre a foto não fosse intencional? Bem, de qualquer forma, agora já não é.

Comment: Marimbondo nada mais é que uma vespa grande.

Comment: @BrunoCosta Este link é sobre como diferenciar vespas de abelhas, e não como selecionar marimbondos dentro de vespas. Por definição, todo himenóptero que não é uma formiga ou uma abelha é uma vespa, mas esta diferenciação não tem nada a ver com a língua portuguesa.

Comment: @RamonMelo Nao é bem assim, o artigo explica como identificar pelo menos duas espécies de vespas. Lá também podes encontrar que marimbondo também pode ser chamado de vespa papel.

Comment: @Jacinto Foi intencional, para proteger leitores com entomofobia. Mas, pensando bem, nenhum deles vai clicar nesta pergunta. hahaha

Comment: @BrunoCosta Marimbondo não é uma espécie de vespa, é um subgrupo não-oficial. A vespa-do-papel, por exemplo, é bem diferente da foto que eu postei aqui, com listras amarelas e menor em tamanho.

Comment: @AndréLyra olha só este mini-marimbondo: http://bugguide.net/node/view/385798/bgpage (só 1,1cm)

Comment: Ramon, imagino que saibas fazer rollback, se quiseres. Mas eh pá, entomofobia é uma coisa; agora entomofotofobia, francamente...

Comment: @Jacinto até sei fazer, mas não julgo necessário. Se alguém deixar uma reclamação, aí penso no caso.

Comment: 1. Não percebo a frase "Os termos taxonômicos em latim podem ser resumidos por "vespas que ferroam seres humanos"", **quais** termos taxonómicos?

Comment: 2. Não é claro se no Brasil os marimbondos são vespas ou não; e se são, então como são chamados no Brasil os não-marimbondos?

Comment: @ANeves termos taxonômicos: "Vespidae, Pompilidae ou Sphecidae". Todo marimbondo é uma vespa. Vespas que não são marimbondos são chamadas só de "vespas" mesmo, algumas espécies polinizadoras são até cultivadas por agricultores.

Comment: Certo ou errado, eu sempre ouvi dizer que os marimbondos são vespas.

Comment: [Marimbondo](https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYiMDcHppkwFzXlbJyh_6e4SiH7_Pp8DTOsFdfMsEsSrVWzsQz) Existem vespas pequenas pretas que podem até ferroar. Mas os Marimbondos são maiores, geralmente você encontra perto de poças de água. E de mexer com eles, eles podem atacar.

Comment: Esse mexeu com o marimbondo https://youtu.be/YeWMqVYL-e4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quem os reconhecer chamar-lhes-á *marimbondos*, mas que eu saiba nós não temos esses bichos em Portugal. A menos que aquilo a que chamamos *vespa* também possa ser classificado como marimbondo.

Eu não sou zoólogo, mas falando como um leigo que cresceu no campo no meio de toda a bicharada, em Portugal, para mim vespa inofensiva é coisa que não existe. Portanto não há necessidade de qualquer diferenciação. Na linguagem corrente em Portugal, uma vespa é um inseto preto e amarelo, parecido com um abelha mas menos gordinho, e―e aqui é que vem o mais importante—cuja ferroada dói que se farta.

Na linguagem corrente de Portugal uma vespa é apenas isto ([“Picaduras de avispa en nuestro perro” (“Picadas de vespa no nosso cão”), Perros QR](http://www.perrosqr.com/picaduras-de-avispa-en-nuestro-perro/)):

[image]

É possível que haja aqui uma diferença entre a linguagem corrente e a científica, porque as definições de *vespa* nos dicionários correspondem mais ou menos à eu dei acima, nomeadamente todos dizem que a vespa tem ferrão ([Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/vespa), [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=vespa), [Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/vespa)). Alguns, como a [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/vespa) ou o dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa, acrescentam que a picada da vespa é muito dolorosa.

Comment: "Marimbondo" não é um termo científico, é idiomático mesmo. Mas, se vocês não têm (ou não reconhecem) vespas não-agressivas, faz sentido que não mesmo haja um nome para diferenciá-las.

Comment: O Priberam tem o verbete [marimbondo](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/marimbondo) e usa a definição "Vespão do Brasil". Seria divertido se fosse assim que vocês o chamassem.

Comment: @Ramon, refiro-me ao significado de *vespa* na linguagem corrente e na científica:  *vespa* na linguagem corrente é mesmo só aquele bicho preto e amarelo; imagino que haja várias espécies, mas as daqui de Portugal, acho que todas picam. Agora poderá haver, mesmo aqui, outros insetos, inofensivos e cientificamente classificados como vespas, que nós não reconheçamos como vespas; não sei dizer.

Comment: @Ramon, dito isto, eu não me aproximo intencional e desnecessariamente de um vespeiro ou colmeia, mas também não saio do meu caminho para me desviar duma vespa ou abelha, e 99,9% das vezes safo-me sem ser picado.

Comment: @Ramon, mas então tu chamarias ou poderias chamar *marimbondos* à vespas comuns de Portugal?

Comment: Infelizmente, eu não tenho escolha. Construíram um campus universitário em território deles e a batalha é permanente. Encontrei [alguns relatos](https://orkut.google.com/c2239502.html) em rede social. E, respondendo a sua pergunta: sim, chamaria, e acredito que meus compatriotas fariam o mesmo.

Comment: Jacinto, e como chamamos aquelas vespas pretas? Eu não sei, acho que chamaria "vespa" ou "vespa preta", mas não acho que sejam vespas porque não têm as listras amarelas e pretas, "o fato de presidiário"...

Comment: @ANeves Podes mostrar-me uma imagem. É que eu não sei do que estás a falar. Estive a ver [as imagens do Google para "vespa preta"](https://www.google.pt/search?q=%22vespa+preta%22&num=50&espv=2&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwig75-P-fHRAhUHuhQKHUvRDa0QsAQIGg&biw=1242&bih=580), mas não reconheço nenhuma delas.

Comment: As minhas pesquisas por esses animais dão sempre nomes de "[vespa tal](http://zoologia2013.blogspot.pt/2013/06/vespa-preto-amarelo-sceliphron-spiriflex.html)"... vou tentar procurar melhor depois.

Comment: @ANeves Estarás a falar dos moscardos? O moscardo é tipo uma mosca comprida e preta. Elas picam e dói muito. Também há as moscas varejeiras, que são uma versão agigantada da mosca comum, mas não picam. Mas isto é tudo da família da mosca. Mesmo o moscardo morde, não tem ferrão para picar.

Comment: @ANeves Isto é porque você está procurando por espécies europeias, e somente brasileiros e angolanos usam o termo. Por exemplo, [esta é de uma família conhecida como "marimbondo-caçador"](https://www.flickr.com/photos/kassapian/2586572980/in/photostream/), que ataca aranhas e arrasta-as para o ninho. Uma espécie desta família é famosa por produzir ferroadas extremamente dolorosas, e vocês a chamam de... ["vespa-caçadora"](http://observador.pt/2016/09/12/estas-sao-as-10-picadas-mais-dolorosas-do-mundo-diz-o-homem-que-ja-as-experimentou-todas/).

Comment: Um novo exemplo: [esta é uma notícia publicada em vários dos maiores jornais brasileiros](http://www.correiobraziliense.com.br/app/noticia/mundo/2013/10/04/interna_mundo,391691/ataques-de-marimbondos-gigantes-matam-mais-de-40-pessoas-na-china.shtml). A vespa mandarina é a maior espécie do mundo, e também a que faz o maior número de vítimas fatais. Como é uma espécie inexistente no país, a notícia chama o inseto pelo nome traduzido, mas o jornal sabe como chamar a atenção de seus leitores: "Ataques de marimbondos gigantes" serviria como título de filme de terror.

Answer (score 2):

> Todo marimbondo é vespa, mas nem toda vespa é marimbondo. Vamos entender: existem cerca de 30 mil espécies de vespas conhecidas e a grande maioria delas não constrói casas (são as chamadas vespas solitárias), mas existe uma minoria que constrói e o marimbondo está nesse grupo.
>
> Por isso, quando levamos uma ferroada de marimbondo há uma justificativa: ele estava tentando defender sua casa. Muitas vespas solitárias escavam o solo com suas mandíbulas e constroem um túnel que termina em um buraco chamado de “cela”. [UFMG](https://www.ufmg.br/online/ndc/publicacoes/qual-a-semelhanca-entre-vespa-e-marimbondo/)

[image: Cacho de Marimbondo]

[image: Marimbondo]

> No Brasil e em Angola são chamadas de marimbondos, as vespas da família Vespidae, Pompilidae ou Sphecidae. [Wikipedia - Vespa](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vespa)

Apesar de vespas de todos os tamanhos e cores poderem ferroar as pessoas, geralmente as que constroem ninhos em árvores ou buracos de paredes e que atacam as pessoas costumam ser chamadas de marimbondos. Muitas delas são grandes e escuras (preta / marrom / avermelhada).

Comment: Assim já estou prevenido para quando as encontrar em Angola ou no Brasil. E tu, quando vieres a Portugal, já sabes: aqui as vespas são amarelas e pretas como as abelhas, não lhe chamamos *marimbondos*, mas elas picam na mesma :) (Ok, normalmente, se as deixarmos em paz, elas também nos deixam em paz; normalmente.)

Comment: @Jacinto Não se deixe enganar pelos biólogos: marimbondos consideram qualquer aproximação como um "ataque" a ser "defendido", mesmo quando pousam em você.

Comment: @RamonMelo Eu falava da minha experiências com as vespas portuguesas. Vespas e abelhas. Normalmente não nos incomodam. Mas já uma vez fui picado por oito abelhas, sem qualquer provocação--ia tranquilamente a subir a estrada de bicicleta.

Comment: @Jacinto Sim, mas eu dizia sobre isto aqui: "Assim já estou prevenido para quando as encontrar em Angola ou no Brasil." Estes bichos são destemidos, a maioria deles preda animais maiores (ou em maior número) do que eles. Já presenciei um destes atacando um pitbull de focinheira, foi uma disputa desleal.

Answer (score 0):

Na realidade não havia marimbondos em Portugal mas agora há. Qual não foi a mj ha surpresa ao encontrar um ninho na minha varanda. Isto só prova mesmo que lixamos o clima pois o marimbondo só se dá em climas tropicais.

Comment: Boas-vindas ao Portuguese SE! Obrigado pela contribuição, mas por favor note que geralmente se esperam respostas bem fundamentadas — por exemplo com referências.